Do we have the structure "to color + adjective (yellow/red etc) + something"?
"off" is an adverb in the structure "turn something <-> off".
Because it is an adverb, we can put it before or after something.
For example, turn the fan off = turn off the fan.
Say there are many fans that are on.
I want to make the fan, which is between the table and the red sofa, to be off.
I would not say "Turn the fan that is between the table and the red sofa off" but "Turn off the fan that is between the table and the red sofa".
If the noun is so long, we put the adverb "off" before the noun.
We have this structure "to color something + adjective".
For example, color the picture yellow.
I don't think we can say "color yellow the picture" because "yellow" is an adjective.
However, what would I do if the noun is too long?
I want to make the picture, which is on the page 20 of the science textbook, to be yellow.
Do we say "Please color the picture which is on the page 20 of the science textbook yellow" or "Please color yellow the picture which is on the page 20 of the science textbook"?

No - "colour yellow the picture" or "paint red the town" would be wrong.
The typical word order of English is: verb (the action) - direct object (who or what the action is done to) - adjective/adjective phrase (describing how or in what manner the action is performed). So "paint the town red" is typical, as is "turn the light off".
The reason "turn off the light" is an acceptable alternative is because "turn off" is a common phrasal verb. It provides all the detail necessary in verb form so as not to need any adjective or adjective phrase to add detail about the manner.
"Colour yellow" or "paint red" are not recognisable phrases, and so cannot be used that way. Phrasal verbs involving paint include "spray-paint" - for example, "I'm going to spray-paint my car red" saves you from having to say "I'm going to paint my car red with a spray can".

I think most writers would avoid the problem by re-wording the instruction.

Find the picture on page 20 of your science textbook and colour it yellow. (not 'the page 20'.)

